# Unable to install python pandas in company environment. Any way to bypass?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I tried to install pandas on python using 3.6 version from command line
    py -3.6 -m pip install pandas 
C:\Users\mnperezp\Pythonpandas>py -3.6 -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03F7E390>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03F7E910>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03F7E770>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03F7EE50>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03F7E4F0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandas/
```

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions:
 )
No matching distribution found for pandas

Then, i tried to store Pandas in the same location where i have python 3.6 and run. I did go to the right directory where the python.exe and pandas-0.21.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl are located.

and use this:

```
python –m pip install pandas-0.21.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Then, i got this.

```
python: can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Could somebody suggest what to do?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are behind a proxy

Try

```
pip install --proxy domain\user:password@proxyaddress:port pandas
```

Comment: Dumb question? how can i know the proxy address?

Comment: Depends what is your OS and what type of proxy. Is more easily ask to your   network admin.

Comment: Ask your IT department to help you.  If they won't help you, interview at other companies that will!